# What is the result type of the bit shift operator?

Tags: c++, types, bit-shift, integer-promotion

Consider the following listing:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(31), int32_t>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(31u), uint32_t>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((signed char)1 << 1), int32_t>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((signed char)1 << 1u), int32_t>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((unsigned char)1 << 1), int32_t>);
// Signed result for unsigned char
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((unsigned char)1 << 1u), int32_t>);
// But unsigned for uint32_t
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(1u << 1u), uint32_t>);
```

It [compiles](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:61,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:61,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype(31),+int32_t%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype(31u),+uint32_t%3E)%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype((signed+char)1+%3C%3C+1),+int32_t%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype((signed+char)1+%3C%3C+1u),+int32_t%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype((unsigned+char)1+%3C%3C+1),+int32_t%3E)%3B%0A//+Signed+result+for+unsigned+char%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype((unsigned+char)1+%3C%3C+1u),+int32_t%3E)%3B%0A//+But+unsigned+for+uint32_t%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype(1u+%3C%3C+1u),+uint32_t%3E)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.17988203122128,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wpedantic+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:20.04845357577933,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.77166439299939,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) fine with GCC and Clang. I am quite confused about `operator<<(uint8_t, uint32_t)`. Why the result is signed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Per [[expr.shift]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift)

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.
> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. [...]

So for `unsigned char` and `int`, the left operand is promoted from `unsigned char` to `int`<sup>1</sup> (see [[conv.prom]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom)), and the result type is the one of the promoted left operand, so `int`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> At least on most common platforms (where `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`), otherwise it might get promoted to `unsigned int` if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

For the `<<` operator, the left operand is promoted with the *integral promotions*. There are some technical details in the integral promotions, but largely they are: Types narrower than `int` are promoted to `int`. Other integer types are unchanged.

The result type of the `<<` operator is the type of its left operand after promotion.

In your examples, `(signed char)1` and `(unsigned char)1` are narrower than `int`, so they are promoted to `int`, which is equivalent to `int32_t` in your C++ implementation. `31` is an `int`, so it remains `int`. `31u` and `1u` are `unsigned int`, so they remain `unsigned int`.